Can separation of variable be used for mixed boundary conditions where boundary conditions are dependent on one another?
Suppose I have a differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{y}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$$ where Boundary condition is:
$$\text{for}~x=0, f(x,y)=0~\text{when}~0\leq y<Y_1$$
and
$$\text{for}~x=0, \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0~\text{when}~Y_1\leq y<Y_2$$
Can this question be solved using the separation of variables? I mean we can clearly see that $x$ and $y$ are dependent on each other, can $f(x,y)$ be simply decomposed as $f(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$?
I have seen book Mixed Boundary Value Problems - 1st Edition - Dean G. Duffy, where questions like these are solved using the separation of variables, but I am not able to get the solutions.
